# Macbook pro Sierra. Slow finder open/save as dialog boxes

Tags: finder, macos

Whenever I click file-open or file-save as in any program, the finder dialog box takes a tremendous amount of time to open (approx 2mins). I have tried all kinds of solutions throughout the web and none have worked, not even temporarily.  Most of the fixes I have seen say that good patches came after Mavericks, but I am running sierra.  I have had the problem even throughout El Capitan, but it was barely a problem. On El Capitan the longest delay was maybe 10 seconds.

A few things I have tried/noticed

- The problem occurs in safe mode, but it does NOT occur on the guest accounts
- Going into Safe Mode doesn't fix the problem
- Deleting the Finder plist doesn't work
- Deleting Icloud caches do not work

Comment: I was thinking about a similar issue I was having a while ago and it was because every time I tried to open the dialog it would try to connect to my NAS.  The NAS had to spin-up before the drive was available for Finder so I had several seconds of delay.  Do you have any external drives that could be slowing it down?

Comment: Unfortunately not.  The only thing I have is the one SSD in my macbook.

Comment: I have the same problem. All apps are slow with the Open dialogs - even changing dirs is a pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after quite a few months of this problem going on.  I decided to sit down for a few hours and find the solution for myself.  Turns out, the solution was rather simple, but it might be a trouble point in other cases more than mine.  Ultimately, My problem was with Icloud.  After removing ICloud functionality from my mac, the problem instantly vanished.  Fortunately, I do not use ICloud at all and instead, opt for Google Drive.  For some, I say this might be a trouble point because it requires removing Icloud files.